# Fetching data inside a for loop in twig Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony

I'm beginner in Symfony, How do I fetch the value of `sub_agent.companyId` in my `company` table on views using symfony?

**Controller:**

```
public function indexAction(Request $request) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $sub_agents = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Sub_agent')
        ->findAll();

    return $this->render('Backend/Sub_agent/index.html.twig', array(
        'sub_agents' => $sub_agents
    ));
}
```

**Template: index.html.twig**

```
{% for sub_agent in sub_agents %}

{{ sub_agent.companyId }} // Get the data of this companyId in my company table

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the company has an relation with the sub_agent entity or not?

If it is a seperated entity you should first get the company and after that get the id of the company entity

try this:

```
{% for sub_agent in sub_agents %}
   {{ sub_agent.company.id }} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I need. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Cool, no problem. Good you check this answer as the correct answer?

Comment: If `company` is either an attribute of sub_agent or an object, then won't work. But if `company` is a method that retrieves the company then it will. However, normally getters should be called `getCompany` or similar. Also, once you have the `Company` object, you can't access the `id` this way directly in Twig, especially since this the ID is normally set as `protected` or `private`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{% for sub_agent in sub_agents %}
 {{ sub_agent.companyId|e }}
{% endfor %}
```

refer : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys

Comment: how do I retrieve the value of that `companyId` in my table company?

Comment: any relation between Sub_agent and company table? pls show ORM

Answer (score -1):

Use your getter. Not sure what it is called for your Entity. Something like this:

```
{% for sub_agent in sub_agents %}
   {{ sub_agent.getId }}
{% endfor %}
```

It should be as easy as that, since you normally can't call the attribute directly, so just use your Entity setters/getters to get/set them.

**EDIT #2 - Based on you didn't mention you had a separate Entity called `Company`**

```
{% for sub_agent in sub_agents %}
   {{ sub_agent.getCompany.getId }}
{% endfor %}
```

The above presumes that the `sub_agent` Entity has a `$company` attribute and the getter is called `getCompany()`. Then `getCompany()` returns a `Company` object, and then the `Company` method `getId()` returns the `Company` ID. You could also use DanBuit's suggestion, but both Chi-Chi and my suggestions are the "typical" way to do it in Twig.

Comment: Both @Chi-Chi and my answers were good suggestions. I'm not sure why the downvote for both of us? You didn't mention that Company was a different Entity. In that case I will modify my answer to show an EDIT #2 to show the normal way to use a getter. Maybe you didn't down vote, but still I don't think the downvote is deserved.